# How to avoid using a number or enum when implementing business logic

Tags: c#

I'm working on implementing come business logic in my C# application.
I'm having trouble fitting the logic into a sane piece of code.
The logic to implement goes like this:

There is a tree of elements, let's say: Project, Country, Region, City. A single Project contains Countries. Countries contains Regions, Region contains Cities and Cities contain data entries. We'll be populating the elements with data entries based on what information is available.

- if *Country*, *Region*, and *City* information is available, push the data to the project and use the info to know where to insert the data entries.
- if *Country* info is not available, create a new *Country* and use *Region* and *City* info to insert the data entries.
- if only city info is available, create a new *Region* inside a new *Country* and use *City* info to put data there.
- if no info is available, create a new *City* inside a new *Region* inside a new *Country* and put the data there.
- if any info is not available out of order (for example *Country* and *Region* are available but not *City*) we have to fall back to the more general case (creating new *Country*, *Region* and *City* in this case).

Additionally:

- when you create a leaf class, you have to provide the parent in the constructor.
- querying about what info is available is expensive.
- I would like to avoid repeating the code that creates new classes.
- I cannot change the implementation of classes `Country`, `Region`, `City`.

My solution below works, but it's ugly and using an integer to control app flow gives me shivers.

**How can I improve the code snippet below?**

```
Country country = null;
Region region = null;
City city = null;

int level;

if (!IsCityInfoAvailable())
{
    // we have to make a new country, region and city
    level = 3;
}
else if (!IsRegionInfoAvailable())
{
    // we have to make a new country and region
    level = 2;
}
else if (!IsCountryRegionAvailable())
{
    // we have to make a new country
    level = 1;
}
else
{
    // we have all the info we need
    level = 0;
}

IDataEntryTarget target;

if (level > 0)
{
    country = new Country(Project, "Unnamed Country");
    target = country;
}
if (level > 1)
{
    region = new Region(country, "Unnamed Region", Region.DefaultRegionSettings);
    target = region;
}
if (level > 2)
{
    city = new City(region, "Unnamed City", 0);
    target = city;
}

// ... proceed with data entry code using `target`...
```

Comment: sorry, what is the level integer supposed to be doing here?

Comment: oh i see, it's just determining the highest level of available info?

Comment: In the future, I would recommend using composition with your class structure. City should be an attribute of region, region is an attribute of country, country is an attribute of Project. This way, you can elegantly bulk handle these by loading them all into a list and controlling them using behaviors defined in the top level class (Project; ie: var population = ProjectList.Where(i => i.Country == "Uraguay").Country.Region.City.Population; or ProjectList.Where(i => i.Country == "USA").AddPhoto(img);

Comment: @Sinaesthetic:can you elaborate? Right now a Project has a list of Countries, a Country has a list of Regions, and so on. Given that, I don't understand how `ProjectList.Where(i => i.Country == "Uraguay").Country.Region.City.Population` would work.

Comment: same thing, just treat the attributes as lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited:** try it like this:  The only question I have is where are city, region & country initialized?  In the Is() methods?

```
Func<Country> GetCountry = () => country ?? (country = new Country(Project, "Unnamed Country"));
Func<Region> GetRegion = () => region ?? (region = new Region(GetCountry(), "Unnamed Region", Region.DefaultRegionSettings));
Func<City> GetCity = () => city ?? (city = new City(GetRegion(), "Unnamed City", 0));

IDataEntryTarget target = null;

if (!IsCityInfoAvailable())
{
    // we have to make a new country, region and city
     target = GetCity();
}
else if (!IsRegionInfoAvailable())
{
    // we have to make a new country and region
    target = GetRegion();
}
else if (!IsCountryRegionAvailable())
{
    // we have to make a new country
    target = GetCountry();
}
```

Comment: Note that the constructors require a reference to the element one level higher, so the above won't work. I could, however, rearrange the if's and use booleans to keep track of what needs to be created, like you did.
Also: yes, I made a mistake! it shouldn't be `@class`, it should be `city`. I was modyfing my code to make it easier to understand outside of my project domain.

Comment: The constructor for `City` will fail, because `region` is either not initialized or null.

Comment: @Dominik Ok, edited it.  Where are city, country and region initialized?  In the `Is()` methods?  That's the way I made this last edit.

Comment: When city information is available, each data entry contains information about the city it should be in. *Multiple* city objects would be created to correspond to the information in the data entries I'm loading. If there is no information about the city, a create a new default city and put all the data entries there. Same goes for regions and countries. Sorry for not making this clear enough.

Comment: But your idea to use `Func<T>` is a good one! I can avoid having to duplicate the constructors that way and just use three if/elses like in your current answer. I'd just call `CreateCountry()`, `CreateRegion()` and `CreateCity()` combinations in each if.

Comment: Mine does that I think, as GetCity will call GetRegion (if city is null) and GetRegion calls GetCountry (if region is null), but glad I could help simplify it for you.

Comment: Yikes! I didn't notice the calls from within those expressions. Your answer is great, thank you!